# Test AngularJS $routeProvider resolve using Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, route-provider

I'm not sure how can i test the results coming on the routeProvider resolve.

1. how can i call certain when in the route provider.
2. how can i test that the return result is what i'm expecting it to be.

In the following example this this is what I'm missing:

Let's say i have th following route provider config:

```
var rt = angular.module("ResolveTest",[]);

rt.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider)
{
  $routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: "rt.html",
    controller: "ResolveCtrl",
    resolve: {
      data: ["$q","$timeout",function($q,$timeout)
      {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function()
        {
          deferred.resolve("my data value");
        },2000);

        return deferred.promise;
      }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

and this is the spec.js file:

```
describe("Testing route provide resolve", function() {

var routes;


it('should test routeProvider', function() {

      inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope) {
          routes = $route;
      });

      // here I would like to check that my data value was resolved from the route.
      // how can i do that?
});
```

can someone give a full working example of how calling the correct route and testing the resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I faced the same problem, so answering it.

The resolved data makes it into **$route.current.locals** property.

You can test it using -

```
it('should test routeProvider', function() {

  inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope) {
      routes = $route;
  });

  // here I would like to check that my data value was resolved from the route.
  expect(routes.current.locals.data).toBe("my data value");
});
```